# Unable to execute SELECT QUERY as PREPARED SQL STATEMENT in php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, postman

I get this error when I test my php file: `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

This is my php code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $stmt = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
    $result->bind_param('s', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($username);
    $result->fetch();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
        echo "Result found";
    }
    else{
        echo "NO";
    }
}
?>
```

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe we need such statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: You have to do a `$result->store_result();` before you can use `$result->num_rows`

Comment: There is a special version of num_rows for statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php Also notice the Object-Oriented vs. Procedural style of how it is used.

Comment: @fredrover You can mix OO and proceedural `mysqli` but I agree its bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Put a check on the outcome of the *prepare*:

```
$result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt) or die ($dbcon->error());
```

And be aware that the number of rows is often zero if you do not call *store_result*, but in your case you can just check the return value of the *fetch* call, so join the fetch with your `if`:

```
if ($result->fetch()) {
   echo "Result found";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

... and drop the use of *num_rows*.

It is not related to your problem, but it's good practice to add a *close* once you don't need the prepared statement anymore:

```
$result->close();
```